# How do I have a const member move-only object without making my object copyable?

Tags: c++, vector, stl, move-semantics

```cpp
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<memory>

class Foo {
 public:
  Foo();

#if 1
  // Destructor for rule of 5.
  ~Foo(){}

  // Move constructor yes.
  Foo(Foo&&) noexcept = default;

  // Move assignment probably won't actually be created because const member variable.
  // Do I need it though? Why would vector need to move-assign?
  Foo& operator=(Foo&&) noexcept = default;

  // Copy no.
  Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
  Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
#endif

 protected:
  // It works if non-const. Broken if const.
  const std::unique_ptr<int> ptr;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Foo> bar;
  bar.reserve(1);
}
```

I get the error (with GCC):

```
static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
```

But why?

To me it looks like both default and move constructor should be fine. Is this in case e.g. I `const_cast` away the const and erase a middle element, the `vector` would maybe try to move-assign to "defrag" the vector? (whereas if it tried to destroy+move-construct, that would work)

In the snipped above `unique_ptr` is standing in for my own move-only type, so this question is not about pointers.

Comment: Do you want the _pointer_ to be `const` or do you want the object it's pointing _at_ to be `const`? In the latter case, just make it: `std::unique_ptr<const int> ptr;`

Comment: If the `unique_ptr` is const, you can't move it, because that would reset its pointer to `nullptr`.

Comment: "// Destructor for rule of 5." Wrong interpretation of rule of 5. The "if you implement 1 then you need to implement all 5" is a simplification. The whole story goes like this: if you feel the need to write 1 of the 5 then most likely your class owns and manages a resource. If your class is responsible with manual management of a resource then you need to implement all 5. In your case your class doesn't manage any resource so you don't need to write the destructor. In fact it is recommended to not write the destructor.

Comment: You can't move something which is const. The default implementation of the move constructor will not work, but you can implement your own move constructor and make a copy of members that can't be moved and move other members that can be moved.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: Like I said this is an example where unique_ptr is standing in for the actual object. This is not about pointers. I am aware of the difference you are talking about.

Comment: @parktomatomi You can't move it, that's right. Hence my comment on the move *assignment*. But you *can* move construct this object. Hmm… or can you… Ah, I see now. I was focusing on the destination in the move, not the rhs. Yes that makes sense.

Comment: @Thomas Yes, but since you used a pointer in the example, I answered with a pointer. The pointer is `const` - it can't be changed to point to something else - much like a pointer in your own class when the whole object is `const`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo my question explicitly says this is not about pointers.

Comment: @Thomas Make an example that makes sense to you then. Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Tfszj9) perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I have a const member move-only object without making my object copyable?

Having a move-only member object makes your class implicitly non-copyable, so there is nothing in particular that needs to be done to achieve that.

---

> I get the error
>
> But why?

Because your class is not satisfy the requirements of being MoveInsertable. This is because it is not move constructible.

> To me it looks like both default and move constructor should be fine.

Move constructor is not fine because of the member that is not movable. The member is non-movable because it is both non-copyable and const.

In conclusion: You can have a class like this, but it cannot be used with `std::vector::reserve` because it is neither copyable nor movable.

Comment: I see. So to be clear, the problem is that I'm trying to move *from* a const member, not that the destination member (at least in the case of move constructor) is const?

Comment: @Thomas Yes. You're trying make changes to a `const` member (in the _moved-from_ object). The constructed object's `const` member can be initialized but then never be assigned to (or moved from). Non-`static` `const` members are a real pain. I have rarely found any use for them.

Comment: @Thomas In move assignment, both would be a problem. Initialising a const object (which is what you do in a constructor) is not a problem, but constness of the source still is.